# What do we need to do to get activity back?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we drive more questions on the site?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-can-we-drive-more-questions-on-the-site)

It seems that we had a great start on this beta but now the activity is really dropping. Is this natural or something to be worried about, and if so what's the best course of action to try and get the site back on track?

Comment: This is pretty much a dupe of http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/165/66 - @Gilles answer is spot on though. Normal, just needs the push through with activity and advertising to get past the dip.

Comment: I've seen a lot of new users in the past few days, which gives me hope.

Answer (score 6):

A great start for a couple of weeks, then a major drop in activity, followed by a long low plateau, a long slow rise, and finally a kicking back into gear, is the lot of most beta sites.

There are three things you need to do for the site to grow:

- Ask good questions.
- Post good answers.
- Advertise.